# Event ID: 2002 Source: IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-event-log, performance-counters, iis

My server is showing on Event Viewer this error every hour.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters
Date:          03/10/14 9:07:42
Event ID:      2002
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MyServer.MyDomain.local
Description:
Setting up Web Service counters failed, please make sure your Web Service counters are registered correctly.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters" Guid="{90303B54-419D-4081-A683-6DBCB532F261}" EventSourceName="W3CTRS" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2002</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-10-03T12:07:42.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2193581</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>MyServer.MyDomain.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Binary>02000780</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Searching through the web, I found many articles saying "this error happens because of corrupted entries on registry". I found many webpages with tutorials or tips to solve this issue on Windows Server 2008 or older but no one worked on my Windows Server 2012.

This are some of the pages I followed instructions:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734941(v=ws.10).aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735037(v=ws.10)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2554336
- http://jesperarnecke.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/corrupt-or-broken-performance-counters-windows-2012/

Do you have another tip of how can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions of this webpage:

- http://www.vikingengineer.com/microsoft/iis-servers-get-iis-w3svc-perfcounters2002-and-iisinfocounters1001-errors-in-application-log/

I did this steps before and I'm not sure why "cutting and pasting" the steps from this website worked. The commands were:

```
cd c:\Windows\Inf\W3SVC
lodctr .\0409\w3ctrs.ini
```

After that, the Warning Event ID 2003 comes up. To solve this warning I followed the instructions from:

- http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/932813/en-us

Typing this command:

```
lodctr /T:W3SVC
```